# Split with whitespace and comma ignoring single digit number at the string end

Tags: c#, regex

This is the format I have:

```
20130101 1700002497,1.320202,1.3203203,0
```

I need to split it as 4 values in a array. The regex I'm using is simple: `\s|\,` but I want to ignore the last zero because it is getting in the array as well as a 5th value. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Is that always a `0` at the end? Or any 1-digit number?

Comment: it is always 1 digit number, not really sure if its always 0.

Comment: *Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool.* — which language are you using? JavaScript?

Comment: Hm sorry, im using c#

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You may add an optional consuming group that would match a single digit at the end of the string:

```
[\s,]+(?:[0-9]$)?
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5cs%2c%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5b0-9%5d%24%29%3f&i=20130101+1700002497%2c1.320202%2c1.3203203%2c0)

**Details**:

- `[\s,]+` - 1 or more whitespaces or commas
- `(?:[0-9]$)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a single digit (`[0-9]`) at the end of the string (`$`).

[image]

In C#:

```
var res = Regex.Split(s, @"[\s,]+(?:[0-9]$)?").Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m));
```

A matching approach to match all numbers but a single digit at the end of the string:

```
[+-]?(?!(?<!^)[0-9]$)[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%2B-%5D%3F%28%3F!%28%3F%3C!%5E%29%5B0-9%5D%5Cr%3F%24%29%5B0-9%5D*%5C.%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%5BeE%5D%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F&i=20130101%201700002497%2C1.320202%2C1.3203203%2C0%0D%0A20130101%201700002497%2C1.320202%0D%0A12%2C2%0D%0A1123.12%0D%0A.12%0D%0A1123&o=m).

Here, `(?!(?<!^)[0-9]$)` lookahead will fail a match if the 1-digit number is at the end, and is not at the start of the string.

C#:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(s, @"[+-]?(?!(?<!^)[0-9]$)[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Its not really helping me because i'm creating a list with 1+ millions of rows and this extra empty string is just overloading.

Comment: It is no overhead, overhead is removing the last digit with `Regex.Replace(s, @"[\s,]+\d$", "")` before splitting.

Comment: You will have to apply post or preprocessing here, so you choose what "overhead" is allowed or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = Regex.Split(s, @"([\d.]{2,})");
```

Comment: This does not return the data the OP asked for

Comment: You should provide some explanation for the code you posted.